# How to disable middle mouse click on touchpad?

Tags: 18.04, mouse, touchpad

I used to disable the middle click on touchpad with the following command:

```
xinput --set-prop 15 307 1
```

but now it gives me this error message:

```
X Error of failed request:  BadAccess (attempt to access private resource denied)
Major opcode of failed request:  131 (XInputExtension)
Minor opcode of failed request:  57 ()
Serial number of failed request:  19
Current serial number in output stream:  20
```

I think I messed up things after I tried to increase the mouse cursor speed but the changes in settings should not remain after reboot.

Is there anything I can try to disable this cancerous feature (middle click).

Comment: have you tried gnome-tweaks?

Comment: three finger tap option?

Comment: Is there a solution to this, in 2022?